# Getting resource not found 404 even URL is correct spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

DepartmentController

```
@RestController
public class DepartmentController {
    
    @Autowired
    DepartmentControllerConsumer departmentService;
   
    @GetMapping("/departments")
    public ResponseEntity<List<DepartmentResponse>> getAllDepartments() {
        ResponseEntity<List<DepartmentResponse>> departments = departmentService.getAllDepartmentsUsingClient();
        return  departments;
    } 

}
```

DepartmentControllerConsumer

```
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
@Service
public class DepartmentControllerConsumer {
    
    public ResponseEntity<List<DepartmentResponse>> getAllDepartmentsUsingClient() {
        List<DepartmentResponse>list=new ArrayList<>();
        WebClient client =WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080/restservice/api/");
        System.out.println(client);
        Flux<DepartmentResponse> value = client.get().uri("departments").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(DepartmentResponse.class);
        list=value.toStream().collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(value.toStream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
        return new ResponseEntity<List<DepartmentResponse>>(list, HttpStatus.OK);
    }   
}
```

The above was the controller and the service classes, Having one endpoint.While calling it from the post man am getting 404 even gave the correct URL path

Comment: Where did you define `/restservice/api/` ?

Comment: That is an another spring boot application in my local, just calling it using webclient from this boot application

Comment: Sicne it is a GET API did you just try in the browser directly or in postman ? 404 comes when we use wrong URIs
Please check whether the below url is working in any browser or postman 

http://localhost:8080/departments/

Comment: The issue is due to the package structure of the project, Resolved the issue by keeping the classes in a correct package, Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if your controller class is not in the same package as source package, you may need to either put them in same package or make use of `@ComponentScan` to scan your package :)