# Why when I access the controller route the html is not found nor does it return data to me with Postman?

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, maven

I have thought that it could be a dependency problem and I have looked at the pom.xml and I consider that I have everything I need

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.home</groupId>
    <artifactId>class</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>class</name>
    <description>Aquí estan las clases</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Then I thought that it could be a problem with the controller that is not returning data or redirecting correctly but I can't think of what it could be

**My controller**

```
@RestController
public class PruebaController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonaService personaService;
    @GetMapping(value="/index",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> index(){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(this.personaService.findAll());
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I do the command -> "spring-boot:run" and go to the link I get -> Error 404
I am also sure that the connection to the database is made perfectly so I only have to rule out that the service is done wrong but I don't know what it could be

**PersonaService.java**

```
public interface PersonaService {
    Page<PersonaDTO> findAll();

    PersonaDTO findByNSS(String NSS);

    PersonaDTO findByNumTarjeta(String numTarjeta);

    void save(PersonaDTO paciente);

    void saveAll(List<PersonaDTO> pacientes);

    void deleteById(Long id);
}
```

and this is my file

**PersonaImpl.java**

```
package Services.Implementation;

import DTO.PersonaDTO;
import Repository.PersonaRepository;
import Services.Interfaces.PersonaService;
import Utils.MHelpers;
import com.example.demo.Persona;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Component
public class PersonaImpl implements PersonaService {

    @Autowired
    private PersonaRepository PersonaRepository;

    @Override
    public Page<PersonaDTO> findAll() {
        Page<Persona> personas = this.PersonaRepository.findAll();

        return personas.map(this::convertToPersonaDTO);
    }

    @Override
    public PersonaDTO findByNSS(String NSS) {
        Optional<Persona> personas = this.PersonaRepository.findByNSS(NSS);

        if (!personas.isPresent()){
            return null;
        }

        return MHelpers.modelMapper().map(personas.get(),PersonaDTO.class);
    }

    @Override
    public PersonaDTO findByNumTarjeta(String numTarjeta) {
        Optional<Persona> personas = this.PersonaRepository.findByNumTarjeta(numTarjeta);

        if (!personas.isPresent()){
            return null;
        }

        return MHelpers.modelMapper().map(personas.get(),PersonaDTO.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void save(PersonaDTO personaDTO) {
        Persona persona = MHelpers.modelMapper().map(personaDTO, Persona.class);
        this.PersonaRepository.save(persona);
    }

    @Override
    public void saveAll(List<PersonaDTO> personas) {
        List<Persona> p = new ArrayList<>();

        for (PersonaDTO persona: personas) {
           Persona pers = MHelpers.modelMapper().map(persona,Persona.class);
           p.add(pers);
        }
        this.PersonaRepository.saveAll(p);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(Long id) {
        this.PersonaRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    private PersonaDTO convertToPersonaDTO(final Persona persona){
        return MHelpers.modelMapper().map(persona,PersonaDTO.class);
    }
}
```

If you need more information tell me

Comment: Can you show project structure? Or if you can't , try adding `@ComponentScan` annotation to specify the package name where your controller resides , usually is the case where scanning doesn't happen if your controller is in another package other than `@SpringBootApplication` class'

Comment: also can you show us the URL you are trying to access?

Comment: @Harsh What is the "@ComponentScan" for, I don't understand what you mean

Comment: @LowCool http://localhost:62946/index -> The port is that because I had to put port 0 for it to choose the one that is available

Comment: @MiguelÁngel : add your project name before `/index`

Comment: @LowCool Not working :(

Comment: can you add the url you are trying in your code?

Comment: @LowCool localhost:62946 now this link because I deleted the route, to see if it works in the main menu

Comment: Basically if your Controller file is in a different package then the main class , then you need @ComponentScan to tell springBoot where you controller and exposed end points are :) , no other reason why a simple end point would not work

Comment: @Harsh oh that makes sense,I am going to try

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69070727/getting-resource-not-found-404-even-url-is-correct-spring-boot/70903361#70903361 Check a similar issue

Comment: @Harsh Now says me this -> `Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-01-24T13:42:55.256+01:00 ERROR 14704 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
`

Comment: Post complete stack trace

Comment: @Harsh Public the entire project?

Comment: Need the complete start up logs , need to see full logs where error is occuring

Comment: @Harsh `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personaRepository' defined in com.CitaMedica.main.Repository.PersonaRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract com.CitaMedica.main.Persona com.CitaMedica.main.Repository.PersonaRepository.findByUser(java.lang.String); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.CitaMedica.main.Persona com.CitaMedica.main.Repository.PersonaRepository.findByUser(java.lang.String); 
`

Comment: @Harsh and this `No property 'user' found for type 'Persona' .`  I don't know but is so confusing

Comment: @Harsh My main problem is that the Tomcat server doesn't start and gives me these errors. When I can start it I will be able to use postman

Comment: Edit and post your repository class as well, need to see "PersonaRepository" class/interface Also check if you have any native query , it is valid, i.e. it can execute on any database engine, if spring identifies issues with your query hence this issue